# How get screenshot of all objects in scene by its bounds

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I generated a model in Unity3d by vertics data. I created BoxCollider, that contains all game objects for the model.

How can I get screenshot of camera view according to the bounds of the model (BoxCollider)?

Here is my model

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  For future reference please make sure your question actually contains a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet, I explain the code with comment:

```
int textureWidth = GameObject.find("UnicGroups").GetComponent<BoxCollider>.size.x; // Width of photo
int texturHeight = GameObject.find("UnicGroups").GetComponent<BoxCollider>.size.y; // Height of photo

// You can add EmptyGameObject to your model
// and move that game object to upper left corner of
// your model. Then you can replace x and y value
// with position of that game object
float x = GameObject.find("UnicGroups/YourEmptyGameObject").transform.Position.x; // x position of upper left corner of screenshot
float y = GameObject.find("UnicGroups/YourEmptyGameObject").transform.Position.y; // Y position of upper left corner of screenshot

// create the texture
Texture2D screenTexture = new Texture2D(textureWidth, texturHeight,TextureFormat.RGB24,true);
screenTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(x, y, textureWidth, texturHeight),0,0);
screenTexture.Apply();

// Save image to file
byte[] dataToSave = screenTexture.EncodeToPNG();
// Set destination path for saving file
string destination = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath,System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss") + ".png");
File.WriteAllBytes(destination, dataToSave);
```

[image]

Comment: Change textureWidth, texturHeight , x, y values to these : 
`int textureWidth = Screen.width;` and
`int texturHeight = Screen.height;` and
`float x = 0f; ` and
`float y = 0f;` 
Do you have image now?

Comment: Yes, also.
my code:
var textureWidth = Screen.width;
var texturHeight = Screen.height;
float x = 0;
float y = 0;
Texture2D screenTexture = new Texture2D((int)textureWidth, (int)texturHeight,TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
screenTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, textureWidth, texturHeight), 0, 0);
screenTexture.Apply();

byte[] bytes = screenTexture.EncodeToPNG();

string filename = "Assets/img/Save.png";

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);

Comment: This is screen shot with size of your camera, For get screen shot with your object size, you need to change `textureWidth` and `texturHeight` to your width and height of your model and change `x` and `y` to location of upper left corner of your model.
Please mark this as answer if it helps.

Comment: I did set textureWidth = width of my model and textureHeight = height of my model, buy I get black screen. Also with textureWidth = Screen.width, textureHeight = Screen.height - too black screen. I am stuck(

Comment: Do you set `float x = 0` and `float y =0` too?

Comment: Yes I set float x = 0 and float y =0.